# Why does the VBA .AutoFilter method remove header rows when sorting, and how can I avoid this?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm trying to sort an expense report by smallest to largest using a value in the K column.

The code 1) fails to sort the code by smallest to largest and 2) removes row 1 (header row).

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
  SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort. _
  SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("K1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
  xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter. _
  Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The code doesn't show any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Sub sIndex()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "K1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:AA10000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Returned a "Run-time error '424': Object required." error box, highlighting the ```SortFields.Clear```

Comment: @mjc5592 I have amended it slightly. Let me know if it works now